# Picture beside user in TFS 2012 admin portal

Tags: tfs, active-directory

I was doing some routine work in TFS 2012.  I was added some Active Directory users to the contributor group of a TFS project.

That's when i noticed that the user had a picture beside their name.

I can't seem to figure out where TFS got that picture. (I've added hundred of users over the years and this is the first time I saw a picture beside someone's name).

I checked the AD properties of the user and there is no thumbnail information.
I opened up the users contact in outlook 2013 and there doesn't seem to be a picture associated with the user.

I'm quite puzzled.

[image: Screenshot of the thumbnail beside the user's name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This user should have edited his profile and changed his picture. You can go to TFS Web Access and click your name--My profile to test this feature:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that existed.